How to move an ellipse. Keep the outside surface of the oval close to the inside surface of the triangle by automatic method?
I want to move an ellipse. Keep the outside surface of the oval close to the inside surface of the triangle.
Is there any automatic way to do this? thank you.
from this

to this


What's the context? Why do you need this?
